# Avoiding double 301 redirects in two stage migration

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

A few months ago, I migrated a client website from an old legacy CMS to Wordpress. Many URLs changed, which I 301 redirected in .htaccess - all seemed well. This was all http, no https, which brings me to ...

Today, I migrated the client onto https and have run into issues with the redirects. Those old URLs are now going through 2x redirects, once to change the URL to https and then again to go the new site URL. I'm not sure how to set up the .htaccess file so those old site http URLs go directly to the new site https URLs, without the unwanted middle step.

I've read that the problem is probably me muddling re-writes and re-directs. I wonder if the Wordpress re-write bit is involved too.

Here's what I've got, with just 2 example URLs to keep it as brief as possible. I've added comments after the # to try and explain my thinking:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# these two lines, I hoped, would redirect from the previous site's http URL to the new site's https URL - but in practice, it is being ignored and it seems to skip to the site-wide rule below it
Redirect 301 /page1 https://www.example.com/folder/page1/
Redirect 301 /page2 https://www.example.com/folder/page2/

# this is the site-wide re-write of new site non-https requests to https - this works fine
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# This is the standard Wordpress rules, this might be impacting what I'm trying to do
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I hope it's clear what I'm trying to do. I think the solution is using all re-writes, and putting them in the correct order, possibly within the Wordpress bit?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Jim

**EDIT (sorry for trying to put this in comments). Following the helpful suggestion, I now have this:**

This is what I'm doing now:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/page1$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/folder/page1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/page2$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/folder/page2/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

But this line: RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] is not working to redirect any other URLs to https

Comment: Have you tried adding specific rewrite rules (I like those much better than mod_alias' `redirect`), e.g. `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^page1$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/folder/page1/ [R=301,L]`? And have you double double checked that it's really /page1, no typo anywhere?

Comment: Test it from a new browser or from command line `curl`

Comment: @janh Yes, thank you, that syntax does work for the specific "old site" pages. The problem that iremains is how to add a site-wide re-write rule that redirects http to https. It needs to go after the list of specific URLs, but when I add it, it is ignored.

Comment: I've updated the original question. Thanks

Comment: You need to repeat the RewriteCond for every RewriteRule, it only works as a condition on the Rule immediately following it.